# Assign Empty Value to Input Field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome Extension where I need to check whether a field in a form submission exists and is not blank, and if so, add that to another form (in lieu of doing a post request).

I'm checking whether it exists and is not blank here:

```
if(document.getElementById("txtBaseAnn").value !== '' && document.getElementById("txtBaseAnn").value !== null) {
                txtBaseAnn = document.getElementById("txtBaseAnn").value 
            } else {
                txtBaseAnn = '';
            }
```

And I'm using that variable to build a form like this:

```
newForm += "<input type='text' name='txtBaseAnn' value='" + txtBaseAnn + "'>";
```

If there's a value in the form, it works. If it's blank, however, what I get is this:

```
<input type='text' name='txtBaseAnn' value>
```

When what I want is this:

```
 <input type='text' name='txtBaseAnn' value=''>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me your issue is that you're trying to select your element with `getElementById` but you are using `name` not `id`.

If you were using `id` correctly, then it wouldn't matter if value was written as `<input type='text' id='txtBaseAnn' value>`

The result of `document.getElementById("txtBaseAnn").value` would be `""`

Comment: The element that I'm validating is created with the following: formAdd += "<input type='text' name='" + data3.fields[i].field + "' id='" +  data3.fields[i].field + "' placeholder='" + data3.fields[i+1].label + "'>";, which includes an ID value.

Comment: I see. So if that's true, then the `value` should be `""` is that not the case? Why do you explicitly want it to be `value=""` on the dom element?

Comment: I thought that value = "" was different from just value?

Comment: the result of `document.getElementById("txtBaseAnn").value` is the same